# Redefine $fetch in nuxt3 with global onRequest handler

Tags: vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js, nuxt3

Is it possible to use global onRequest handler to $fetch with Nuxt3, to add specific data on each request?
With nuxt2 and axios it was simple

```
/plugins/axios.js

export default function ({ $axios, store, req }) {
  $axios.onRequest((config) => {
    if (config.data) {
      config.data.test = '123';
    } else {
      config.data = { test: '123' };
    }
    return config;
  });
}
```

But how achieve same goal on Nuxt3 and $fetch?

Answer (score 11):

Nuxt v3.3.2 seems to be using `globalThis.$fetch` for it's useFetch requests, which is an instance of `ofetch`.

I made a plugin `ofetch.ts` with the following content:

```
import { ofetch } from 'ofetch'
import { useAuthStore } from '~/store/auth'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((_nuxtApp) => {
  globalThis.$fetch = ofetch.create({
    onRequest ({ _request, options }) {
      const authStore = useAuthStore()
      if (authStore.isAuthenticated) {
        options.headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${authStore.token}` }
        console.log(options)
      } else {
        console.log('Not authenticated')
      }
    },
    onRequestError ({ error }) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  })
})
```

this plugin checks my `auth` pinia store for the token and if it is present, sets the headers.

Similar approach can probably be used for other `ofetch` interceptors:
[ofetch docs](https://github.com/unjs/ofetch#%EF%B8%8F-interceptors)

Comment: As described in Nuxt docs (https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/advanced/use-custom-fetch-composable), you should use `globalThis.$fetch = $fetch.create` instead of `ofetch.create`. In my tests doing it with `ofetch.create` will break the `@nuxt/test-utils` based test to this kind of error: FetchError: [GET] "/_nuxt/builds/meta/test.json": <no response> Failed to parse URL from /_nuxt/builds/meta/test.json``

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so [Nuxt3 $fetch](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/dollarfetch#fetch) documentation says:

> Nuxt uses ofetch to expose globally the $fetch helper...

When we jump into [ofetch documentation](https://github.com/unjs/ofetch#%EF%B8%8F-interceptors) we can see the Interceptors section. This gives us some options to do what you are trying to achieve. My suggestion is this:

Create a `http` [composable](https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/auto-imports/composables#composables) (or anyother name you wish):

```
// composables/use-http.js
const opts = {
  async onRequest({ request, options }) {
    // Add your specific data here
    options.query = { t: '1234' }
    options.headers = { 'Authorization': 'my_token' }
  }
}

export default () => $fetch.create(opts)
```

And here we are making usage of the `onRequest` interceptor from ofetch

> onRequest is called as soon as ofetch is being called, allowing to modify options or just do simple logging.

There you can add any data you want, if you need you can create the logic to pass parameters to this composable and so on...

Now, to actually fetch the data (use the composable):

```
const http = useHttp() // useHttp is auto-imported
const data = await http('/url') // will trigger the interceptor
```

Comment: When I tried wrap into composables - I get an error on second request Error: nuxt instance unavailable.

Comment: Can you share the composable definition and where you are triggering it?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using the localStorage where you store the token

```
    import { ofetch } from "ofetch";

    export default defineNuxtPlugin((_nuxtApp) => {
        globalThis.$fetch = ofetch.create({
            onRequest({ request, options }) {
            if (typeof localStorage !== "undefined") {
                options.headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}` };
            }
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: Simple, effective solution. Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a interesting way suggested by Nuxt team, it allows you to customize the fetch request with default values and user authentication token:

https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/advanced/use-custom-fetch-composable

It's a custom composable (extracted from the above example):

```
import type { UseFetchOptions } from 'nuxt/app';

export function useCustomFetch<T>(
  url: string | (() => string),
  options: UseFetchOptions<T> = {}
) {
  return useFetch(url, {
    ...options,
    $fetch: useNuxtApp().$customFetch,
  })
}
```